# Char array with non-constant size while initialiazing

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, constants

I need in C++ char array that is while initialiazing non-constant size. Size have to be non-constant cause it's generated from function and can't be used vector cause this char array will be used for reading and writing to files. Example:

```
int i = functionToGetvalue();
unsigned char ch[i];
file1 >> ch;
file2 << ch;
```

Comment: You can't do it like that. you will need to use `new` (and don't forget to `delete[]` it once your done)

Comment: "can't be used vector cause this char array will be used for reading and writing to files."  - you can do that with vectors or strings.

Comment: What does `functionToGetvalue` do? You might be able to mark it `constexpr`.

Comment: *can't be used vector cause this char array will be used for reading and writing to files.* -- Who gave you this false information?  `std::vector<unsigned char> c(i);  unsigned char *ch = &c[0]; file1>> ch; file2 << ch;`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 `functionToGetvalue` loads data from storage so it can't be `constexpr`.

Comment: Variable length arrays are not legal in C++ yet supported as an extension with some compilers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie information about vector gave me compiler. String can't be used cause it requires to load just some bytes and copy and string have non-constant size.

Comment: @DavidHusička -- Do you want another example that shows you're wrong about `std::string`?

Comment: Show use the file and what you need to read and we can show you how to do it in a sane manner.

Comment: I think your question does only cope a part of your problem. The way you try to solve your problem does not work. Maybe you can specify the whole scenario, then we can maybe help you to find a better design.

Answer (score 5):

The premise is wrong. While there are reasons to prefer c-style arrays (or `std::array`) over vectors, yours is certainly not the one. You can certainly use `std::vector` to read and write to the file, since it is guaranteed to be contiguous in memory.

Example:

```
std::vector<char> vec;
vec.resize(255);
ssize_t sz = read(fd, vec.data(), vec.size());
```

In your original example, you are using formatted streams I/O, and in this case, `std::string` is a best tool:

```
std::string str;
file1 >> str; // reads up to the next white space into str
```

Comment: It don't help cause I need to load specific part of file that is on specific position. The second thing that part can contain spaces so it can't be ended with spaces.

Comment: @DavidHusička, anything you need c-style arrays for you can do with the vector with regards to data loading. Post the actual code with c-style array and I will show you how to do it with vector.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I am yet to see a case when `std::unique_ptr<[]>` would have any benefit over `vector` (apart from, may be, inside the vector implementation itself).

Comment: @NathanOliver if the OP wants to shoot into foot, he certainly can, but he didn't show any reason yet, why to provide him with some hacked array solution, where the `std::vector<>` fits ideally. (and I can imagine some obscure reasons, why not `std::vector`, then again almost none of them would survive connection to "reading files", as that is essentially slow, so the implementation of the container doesn't matter)

Comment: @SergeyA Thanks for that offer to rewrite my code to vector!!! My code bit chenged from yesterday but it's practicaly same. The commented code is how I'd like it to work and the uncommented code is working but slow equivalent of that. Link is: [link](https://bydave.net/codehelp/codehelp.txt)